# How to check a checkbox in a web page which has a dynamic values , Using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen tutorials it is very informative and very easy to understand.

I have doubt in clicking a check box in a website using EXCEL VBA
the check box values will be dynamic.It seems to be very challenging for me. If someone helps me to  fix this i will feel awesome.
I have mentioned below the HTML elements for your reference.

Requirement is to select qualifer code (2015, 2018 & KD)  and delete.

```
Sub Editing_APA_Qualifiers()
```

Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim SHELL_OBJECT
SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)

IE.Visible = True

```
'navigate URL

IE.navigate "URL"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Set Doc = IE.document

' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
  NumRows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

  ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
  For intRow = 2 To NumRows

  IE.Visible = True

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Doc.getElementsByName("chkDel").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & intRow).Value(0).Click
Doc.getElementsByName("chkDel").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("C" & intRow).Value(0).Click
Doc.getElementsByName("chkDel")(7).Click
Doc.getElementById("Delete").Click
objShell.SendKeys "{Enter}"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Doc.getElementById("lstQualifierTypes").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E1").Value
Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

Doc.getElementById("lstQualifiers").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("E2").Value
Doc.getElementById("ADD").Click
```

Next

End Sub

> So in these how we can select the check boxes.

```
For your easy reference
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="0|MY|2018~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="1|MY|2017~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="2|MY|2016~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="3|MY|2015~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="4|VT|L~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="5|VL|KD~"></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="6|VL|K#~"></td>
```

```html
<tbody><tr style="background-color:#ada5bd">
                                <th>&nbsp;</th>
           <th class="center">Del</th>
    <th class="center">Qualifier Type</th>
    <th class="center">Qualifier Code </th>
    <th class="center">Abbreviation </th>
    <th class="center">Print </th>
    <th class="center">Rev </th>
    <th class="center">User Id </th>
    <th class="center">Date </th></tr>

<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="MY" QC="2018" -->
<!-- UpdateId:VKUMARAG -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType0" value="MY">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode0" value="2018">
<input type="hidden" name="Print0" value="Y">
<tr id="tr0"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(0)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="0|MY|2018~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
MY</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
2018</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
Eff: Ineff:  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
VKUMARAG</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
06-mar-2018</td>
</tr>

<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="MY" QC="2017" -->
<!-- UpdateId:VKUMARAG -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType1" value="MY">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode1" value="2017">
<input type="hidden" name="Print1" value="Y">
<tr id="tr1"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(1)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="1|MY|2017~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
MY</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
2017</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
Eff: Ineff:  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
VKUMARAG</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
27-may-2016</td>

</tr>

<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="MY" QC="2016" -->
<!-- UpdateId:ACYRUS3 -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType2" value="MY">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode2" value="2016">
<input type="hidden" name="Print2" value="Y">
<tr id="tr2"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(2)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="2|MY|2016~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
MY</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
2016</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
Eff: Ineff:  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
ACYRUS3</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
17-nov-2015</td>
</tr>

<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="MY" QC="2015" -->
<!-- UpdateId:APIMPORT -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType3" value="MY">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode3" value="2015">
<input type="hidden" name="Print3" value="Y">
<tr id="tr3"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(3)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="3|MY|2015~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
MY</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
2015</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
Eff: Ineff:  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
APIMPORT</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
20-sep-2013</td>
</tr>
<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="VT" QC="L" -->
<!-- UpdateId:APIMPORT -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType4" value="VT">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode4" value="L">
<input type="hidden" name="Print4" value="Y">
<tr id="tr4"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(4)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="4|VT|L~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
VT</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
L</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
Truck  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
APIMPORT</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
20-sep-2013</td>
</tr>
<!-- Printing -->
<!-- QT="VL" QC="KD" -->
<!-- UpdateId:VKUMARAG -->
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType5" value="VL">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode5" value="KD">
<input type="hidden" name="Print5" value="Y">
<tr id="tr5"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" onclick="return radio_onclick(5)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="5|VL|KD~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
VL</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
KD</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
RANGER ICA  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
VKUMARAG</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
23-apr-2020</td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierType6" value="VL">
<input type="hidden" name="QualifierCode6" value="K#">
<input type="hidden" name="Print6" value="Y">
<tr id="tr6"><td width="1"> <input type="radio" name="rdOperation" language="javascript" onclick="return radio_onclick(6)"> </td>
<td width="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkDel" value="6|VL|K#~"></td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
VL</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
K#</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
RANGER OLD  </td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
Y</td>
<td class="center">&nbsp;
A</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
APIMPORT</td>
<td class="left">&nbsp;
20-sep-2013</td>
</tr>

 </tbody>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using css attribute = value selectors with contains operator (*). That way you can specify the static part of attribute value to match on, along with the node type attribute.

E.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("[type=checkbox][value*='0|MY|2018']").click
```

Here I assume that `0|MY|2018` is static within the target node.

Comment: No these values and index will vary in each cases. In the above yellow box I have mentioned how Excel input files looks and three scenarios  below that I have mentioned the requirements too. In 1st scenario value = '0|MY|2018'. ,2nd scenario='0|MY|2017'. ,3RD Scenario ='0|MY|2016'.

Comment: Also please see the attached image how it looks

Comment: Use the same principle to select each of the other check boxes as appropriate. I'm finding it hard to follow your explanation of what is required in the question. It should however, still boil down to the same syntax when making a selection.

Comment: I Have updated the images for the better understanding . Can any one assist me on this.